# Give less weight to burninate requests? (as Hot Meta Posts)

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, community-bulletin

These days I've noticed that most Featured posts on meta websites (I've checked SU and SO) are about burninate requests. I guess it's because it's easy to quickly agree/disagree (upvote/downvote) with a request, which push them up the Featured posts.

However, although these posts are important, I wonder if they could be given a slightly lesser weight so as to make others, non-burninate request posts, more visible?

Comment: Retagged, this is a request to change the algorithm of Community Bulletin questions, in per site meta.